# GWT I18N - Display a String out of a list

Tags: java, gwt

I'm kinda new to GWT. I want to display a certain string in my browser. This string depends on what components are updating and the amount of updating components can vary. The components that are updating are saved in a `List<String>`.

This is my code i use at the moment

```
public interface ComplexMessages extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages {

        @DefaultMessage("Updating firmware on component(s): <br/> {0, list, text}")
        @Key("componentUpdateStatus")
        @AlternateMessage({
            "one", "Updating firmware on component(s): <br/> {0, list, text}"
        })
        String componentUpdateStatus(@PluralCount(DefaultRule_en.class) List<String> components);
```

When i trigger my components to update it displays the message:

"Updating firmware on components: 2".

Instead of

"Updating components: Component 1, Component 2.

(in this situation 2 components were updating).

I red something about using `{0, list, text}` to display the string of a list, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Does anyone know if it is possible to  display multiple and a variable amount strings in one GWT message by retrieving them out of a `List<String>`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove spaces from the format: `{0,list,text}` and it works. Tested.

Comment: @Adam  *facepalms* it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Adam Please post your comment as an answer so it's obvious for further site visitors that this was the solution.

Comment: @Baz I've posted it as an answer with links to the docs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [message format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for [lists](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nPluralForms.html#Lists) doesn't like spaces in it.

Just remove spaces from the format: `{0,list,text}` and it will work. Tested.